# Uncaught TypeError: map is not a function In Reactjs with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am new in React and Firebase database. I am getting error while try to print data using map.

[image: SNAP01]

basically I am using firebase-database and I have displayed the list of all the days for the project including the total amount of hours. under each day I want to show the worker name including the amount of hours worked for single user for that day. Here is Screen-shot

[image: SINGLE USER]

Here is my Firebase Data

[image: FIBERBASE]

as you see in Database under 0 key users details are given but not under key 1 and 2

now I am getting error while print user_name while try to access row.users.map() as given under code.

```
<Table className="MyTable">
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <StyledTableCell>Dato</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell>User Name</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell align="right">Timer</StyledTableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {props.data.dayWiseHours.map(row => (
      <StyledTableRow key={row.date}>
        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {`${row.date}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell component="td" scope="row">
          {  row && row.users &&  
              row.users.map((subData, subindex) =>
                  <span key={subindex}>{subData.user_name}</span> 
              )
          }
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="right">
          {`${row.hour}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
      </StyledTableRow>
    ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

If I try under given code its working fine

```
<TableBody>
    {props.data.dayWiseHours.map(row => (
      <StyledTableRow key={row.date}>
        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {`${row.date}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell component="td" scope="row">
          { row && row.users &&  row.users['-LjuTOzAhVpku-hDFUJ7'].user_name ? row.users['-LjuTOzAhVpku-hDFUJ7'].user_name : "--" }
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="right">
          {`${row.hour}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
      </StyledTableRow>
    ))}
  </TableBody>
```

but key :  `row.users['-LjuTOzAhVpku-hDFUJ7']` will not be always same.

Thanks

Comment: to me it looks like `row.users` is an object not array. You can `map` over array only. To iterate over an object you can use `Object.keys(obj)`. Can you check and let me know the data type of `row.users`.

Comment: You are right row.users is an object. http://prntscr.com/otdngs, sorry i dn't have database access

Comment: problem is solved with Object.keys(obj). Thanks for your help

Comment: added answer for completeness sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my problem  by using @Vaibhav example please check under given Code

```
{ Array.isArray(props.data.dayWiseHours) ? props.data.dayWiseHours.map(row => (
      <StyledTableRow key={row.date}>
        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {`${row.date}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
            { row.users? 
              (
                Object.keys(row.users).map( userKey => (
                <> <span> { row.users[userKey].user_name? row.users[userKey].user_name : "N/A" } - Working Hours : {row.users[userKey].hour} </span><br/></> 
                ))
              ) : "--"      
            }

        </StyledTableCell>
        <StyledTableCell align="right">
          {`${row.hour}\n`}
        </StyledTableCell>
      </StyledTableRow>
    )) : "" 
}
```

and output is :

[image: my final result]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `row.users` is an `Object`, you can use map on `Array` only. To iterate over an `Object` you can do something like this:

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

Object.keys(object1).map((key) => {
  console.log('key:', key);
  console.log('value:', object1[key]);
});
```

First create an Array of the keys of the Object, then map that Array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error while accessing subData.user_name, the property user_name might not exist in that particular subData object.
Add a null check for the property as well while printing the user_name

```
subData.user_name ? subData.user_name : ""
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i have already tried this, nothing happended